# Calling MVC4 web api controller in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

I am using MVC 3 application and used web api controller.

I want to call a method with parameters .

But when I try to call the method I get Internal Server error(500)
My global.asax is:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "PostMethod2",
  routeTemplate: "api/mycontroller/{a}/{b}",
);
```

Should I add any code to application_start of Global.asax to route to the parameterized method?

Comment: Please show the caller and the callee code.

Comment: Are you able to view what the error is?

Comment: caller is just url:http://localhost/api/contr/getcall/2   and callee is

Comment: public void getcall(int a)
{}

Comment: A 500 error usually indicates your method is throwing an uncaught exception. What happens if you run the Web API in the debugger? Does it catch any exceptions when it receives the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route configuration doesn't seem legit, a proper one would look like below

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "PostMethod2",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{a}",
);
```

Note, "{controller}" and "{action}" can't be random. MVC uses it to map to your controller and action(method) respectively.  {a} will be mapped to your parameter "int a". MVC uses mapping by convention.

Answer (score 0):

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Profile", "{Link}.{Id}.aspx", "~/Profile.aspx");
```

Example be helpful!
Link and Id is argument